# unable to verify webhook

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I have a webhook which delivers Push event payloads to a Google Cloud Function. My nodejs code looks like this:

```
function validateRequest (req) {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      const digest = crypto
        .createHmac('sha1', '12345')
        .update(JSON.stringify(req.body))
        .digest('hex');

      if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] !== `sha1=${digest}`) {
        const error = new Error('Unauthorized');
        error.statusCode = 403;
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.log('Request validated.');
      }
    });
}
```

I have double and triple checked that the secret token (
12345') in the code matches the secret in the webhook. Yet, the sha computed by this code does not equal the sha sent by GitHub.  This code was taken verbatim from https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/github-auto-assign-reviewers-cloud-functions. Has the hashing method GitHub uses changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that webhook needs to send content type `application/json` not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.